# Is this DTD wrong for the given XML file

Tags: xml, dtd, xml-validation

**XML** (from https://github.com/SMAPPNYU/ProgrammerGroup/blob/master/LargeDataSets/sample-xml.xml)

```xml
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<?xml-stylesheet href="catalog.xsl" type="text/xsl"?>
<!DOCTYPE catalog SYSTEM "catalog.dtd">
<catalog>
    <product description="Cardigan Sweater" product_image="cardigan.jpg">
        <catalog_item gender="Men's">
            <item_number>QWZ5671</item_number>
            <price>39.95</price>
            <size description="Medium">
                <color_swatch image="red_cardigan.jpg">Red</color_swatch>
                <color_swatch image="burgundy_cardigan.jpg">Burgundy</color_swatch>
            </size>
            <size description="Large">
                <color_swatch image="red_cardigan.jpg">Red</color_swatch>
                <color_swatch image="burgundy_cardigan.jpg">Burgundy</color_swatch>
            </size>
        </catalog_item>
        <catalog_item gender="Women's">
            <item_number>RRX9856</item_number>
            <price>42.50</price>
            <size description="Small">
                <color_swatch image="red_cardigan.jpg">Red</color_swatch>
                <color_swatch image="navy_cardigan.jpg">Navy</color_swatch>
                <color_swatch image="burgundy_cardigan.jpg">Burgundy</color_swatch>
            </size>
            <size description="Medium">
                <color_swatch image="red_cardigan.jpg">Red</color_swatch>
                <color_swatch image="navy_cardigan.jpg">Navy</color_swatch>
                <color_swatch image="burgundy_cardigan.jpg">Burgundy</color_swatch>
                <color_swatch image="black_cardigan.jpg">Black</color_swatch>
            </size>
            <size description="Large">
                <color_swatch image="navy_cardigan.jpg">Navy</color_swatch>
                <color_swatch image="black_cardigan.jpg">Black</color_swatch>
            </size>
            <size description="Extra Large">
                <color_swatch image="burgundy_cardigan.jpg">Burgundy</color_swatch>
                <color_swatch image="black_cardigan.jpg">Black</color_swatch>
            </size>
        </catalog_item>
    </product>
</catalog>
```

**DTD**

```
<!ELEMENT catalog (product)>
<!ELEMENT product (catalog_item+)>
<!ELEMENT catalog_item (item_number,price,size+)>
<!ELEMENT size (color_swatch+)>
<!ELEMENT item_number (#PCDATA)>
<!ELEMENT price (#PCDATA)>
<!ELEMENT color_swatch (#PCDATA)>


<!ATTLIST product description "Cardigan Sweater" CDATA>
<!ATTLIST product product_image "cardigan.jpg" CDATA>
<!ATTLIST catalog_item gender ("Mens"|"Womens") CDATA>
<!ATTLIST size description ("Small"|"Medium"|"Large"|"Extra Large") CDATA>
<!ATTLIST color_swatch image ("red_cardigan.jpg"|"burgundy_cardigan.jpg"|"navy_cardigan.jpg"|"black_cardigan.jpg") CDATA>
```

---

For the XML code above I have tried DTD as below but I couldn't validate it. Please check what is wrong with my DTD. What changes need to be made in the DTD so the XML code can be validated without any error?

Comment: Please edit your question to include the XML document (don't add it as a link), the code or command which validates the XML document and the full error message you get.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your DTD is invalid because of the ATTLIST declarations for `gender`, `description` (`product` element), and `image`. The values in the [enumerations](https://www.w3.org/TR/REC-xml/#NT-EnumeratedType) shouldn't be quoted.

Further more, the values should be valid [NMTOKEN](https://www.w3.org/TR/REC-xml/#NT-Nmtoken) (name token) types which means they can't contain spaces (so `Extra Large` would need to become `ExtraLarge`, `Extra_Large`, etc. in both the DTD and the XML instance).

So to modify the DTD to make the XML valid those ATTLIST declarations would need to change to:

```
<!ATTLIST catalog_item gender (Mens|Womens) #REQUIRED>
<!ATTLIST size description (Small|Medium|Large|ExtraLarge) #REQUIRED>
<!ATTLIST color_swatch image (red_cardigan.jpg|burgundy_cardigan.jpg|navy_cardigan.jpg|black_cardigan.jpg) #REQUIRED>
```

Note that I made the attributes required (`#REQUIRED`) but you could make them `#IMPLIED` (optional) or give them a default value (wrap the value in quotes). See https://www.w3.org/TR/REC-xml/#sec-attr-defaults for more info.

You'd also need to change the `description` attribute value from "Extra Large".

Another thing; in your XML you use "Men's" and "Women's" as values for the `gender` attribute. You'd need to change those to "Mens" and "Womens".

I also noticed that you use default values in the attributes for the `product` element. This doesn't make sense. What happens when you have a second product that isn't a "Cardigan Sweater"?

I think you should change those declarations to:

```
<!ATTLIST product 
    description   CDATA #REQUIRED 
    product_image CDATA #REQUIRED>
```

Notice that I combined both declarations into one and formatted for readability. This is not necessary, but does make it easier to read in my opinion.

One last thing; having an enumeration for `image` on `color_swatch` doesn't make sense either. You'd have to have every image for every product listed in it. Maybe change it to:

```
<!ATTLIST color_swatch image CDATA #REQUIRED>
```

**Updated DTD** (also moved ATTLIST declarations under corresponding ELEMENT declarations. this is just personal preference.):

```
<!ELEMENT catalog (product)>

<!ELEMENT product (catalog_item+)>
<!ATTLIST product 
    description   CDATA #REQUIRED 
    product_image CDATA #REQUIRED>

<!ELEMENT catalog_item (item_number,price,size+)>
<!ATTLIST catalog_item gender (Mens|Womens) #REQUIRED>

<!ELEMENT size (color_swatch+)>
<!ATTLIST size description (Small|Medium|Large|ExtraLarge) #REQUIRED>

<!ELEMENT item_number (#PCDATA)>
<!ELEMENT price (#PCDATA)>

<!ELEMENT color_swatch (#PCDATA)>
<!ATTLIST color_swatch image CDATA #REQUIRED>
```

**Updated XML**

```xml
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<?xml-stylesheet href="catalog.xsl" type="text/xsl"?>
<!DOCTYPE catalog SYSTEM "catalog.dtd">
<catalog>
    <product description="Cardigan Sweater" product_image="cardigan.jpg">
        <catalog_item gender="Mens">
            <item_number>QWZ5671</item_number>
            <price>39.95</price>
            <size description="Medium">
                <color_swatch image="red_cardigan.jpg">Red</color_swatch>
                <color_swatch image="burgundy_cardigan.jpg">Burgundy</color_swatch>
            </size>
            <size description="Large">
                <color_swatch image="red_cardigan.jpg">Red</color_swatch>
                <color_swatch image="burgundy_cardigan.jpg">Burgundy</color_swatch>
            </size>
        </catalog_item>
        <catalog_item gender="Womens">
            <item_number>RRX9856</item_number>
            <price>42.50</price>
            <size description="Small">
                <color_swatch image="red_cardigan.jpg">Red</color_swatch>
                <color_swatch image="navy_cardigan.jpg">Navy</color_swatch>
                <color_swatch image="burgundy_cardigan.jpg">Burgundy</color_swatch>
            </size>
            <size description="Medium">
                <color_swatch image="red_cardigan.jpg">Red</color_swatch>
                <color_swatch image="navy_cardigan.jpg">Navy</color_swatch>
                <color_swatch image="burgundy_cardigan.jpg">Burgundy</color_swatch>
                <color_swatch image="black_cardigan.jpg">Black</color_swatch>
            </size>
            <size description="Large">
                <color_swatch image="navy_cardigan.jpg">Navy</color_swatch>
                <color_swatch image="black_cardigan.jpg">Black</color_swatch>
            </size>
            <size description="ExtraLarge">
                <color_swatch image="burgundy_cardigan.jpg">Burgundy</color_swatch>
                <color_swatch image="black_cardigan.jpg">Black</color_swatch>
            </size>
        </catalog_item>
    </product>
</catalog>
```